# System.ArgumentException using FileStream

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, client-server, system.io.file

Instead of reading all at once, I first create a `FileStream` to open the file, read into a buffer, then call `NetworkStream.write()` to write its content.

Here's the code.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    try
    {
        int len = (int)fs.Length;
        byte[] data = new byte[len];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int count, sum = 0;
        while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, sum, len - sum)) > 0)
        {
            netstream.Write(buffer,sum,len-sum);
            sum += count;  
        }
...
```

It's throwing the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

I don't see any array out of bound issue here .

Suggestions please

Comment: It looks like you are reading `len` bytes to buffer of size `bufferSize`. Since `len == fs.Length` and `bufferSize < fs.Length` it throws exception.

Comment: read from stream into `data` variable or read in chunks. I assume, that you want to read data in chunks into buffer, but you are doing it wrong. `len-sum` forces stream to read all bytes at once (since `len = fs.Length` and `sum = 0`).

Comment: Should keeping `buffer==len` a wise ?

Comment: Yes,i want it in chunks

Comment: No. I think it should be `fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)`. The same thinkg ing `netstream.Write`. The second argument means the offset in `buffer` so it sohuld be `0` since you want to store data from the beggining of buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offset and Length should be based on Buffer length not the whole file, here is an example of reading chucked data from a `FileStream` and write it to another stream :

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                while (true)
                {
                    var count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (count == 0) break;
                    netstream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
        }
```